# How to wait that closure is done before presenting a viewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, closures

When I press secondButton before article is not downloaded, the ArticleViewController is empty because showArticleView(section) is executed before the closure is done.

How can I wait that the completion is finish to execute  showArticleView(section) method.

Controller should not be presented without datas.

```
 @IBAction func secondButtonPressed() {
        if let data = issue.data, let article = data.getTableOfContents.first {
            downloadArticles(for: article)
        }
    }

private func downloadArticles(for section: IssueDataSection) {
    if let mainPage = section.pages.first {
        currentArticleDownload = issue.mediaManager.download(page: mainPage.intValue, loadingDelegate: self, completion: { medias in
            if let medias = medias {
                medias.articles(for: section) { _ in
                    self.showArticleView(section)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

private func showArticleView(_ section: IssueDataSection?) {
    if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "IssueViewer", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ArticleViewController") as? ArticleViewController {
        controller.issue = issue
        if let section = section {
            controller.section = section
        }
        controller.showMagHandler = {
            self.firstButtonPressed()
        }
        controller.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Completion Handler block

Answer (score 0):

Maybe controller is not presented from main thread.

Instead of `self.showArticleView(section)`  try this

```
   DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
       self.showArticleView(section)
   })
```

Instead of `async` you may try `asyncAfter(.now()+0.5,...` to allow more time for the page to download.